# Change directory in Node.js command prompt

Tags: node.js, cmd, directory

I want to move to another directory in Node.js command prompt but when I open the Node.js cmd window it doesn't show me any path. Here is the screenshot of the Node.js cmd window:

[image]

Now if i want to change directory to `D:\abc` then how can i do it here?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

That isn't the Node.js command prompt window. That is a language shell to run JavaScript commands, also known as a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

In Windows, there should be a **Node.js command prompt** in your Start menu or start screen:

[image: Windows Search for node.js]

Which will open a command prompt window that looks like this:

[image: Node.js command prompt window]

From there you can switch directories using the `cd` command.

Comment: I am  not able to change the directory using the shown command prompt.

Comment: Even I am not able to change directory. Any inputs?

Comment: @Meghaa I've added a new screenshot showing how to change drives and directories

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: Thanks a lot

Comment: @Megha For example, in my case I wanted to change directory to `C:\Test`. When I ran `>C:` it changed the directory to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` that is the install directory of nodejs on my Windows 10. I than ran `cd c:\Test` and it changed the command line path to `c:\Test>`.

Answer (score 25):

To switch to the another directory
process.chdir("../");

Comment: You can also drop the trailing slash (ie. `process.chdir("..")`).

Answer (score 8):

If you mean to change default directory for "Node.js command prompt", when you launch it, then (Windows case)

1. go the directory where NodeJS was installed
2. find file nodevars.bat
3. open it with editor as administrator
4. change the default path in the row which looks like

   ```
   if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
   ```

with your path. It could be for example

```
    if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "c://MyDirectory/"
```

if you mean to change directory once when you launched "Node.js command prompt", then execute the following command in the Node.js command prompt:

```
     cd c:/MyDirectory/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the \d [dir] attribute to the cd command like this:

```sh
cd \d %yourdir%:\
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open file `nodevars.bat`
2. Just add your path to the end,
   `"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% /file1/file2/file3`
3. Save file `nodevars.bat`

This work even with Swedish words

Answer (score -2):

Type **.exit** in command prompt window, It terminates the node repl.

Answer (score -2):

**.help** will show you all the options. 
Do **.exit** in this case