# Node.js express serve file from drive D

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to serve a shared folder from my drive`D:/` using node.js and express?

```
 app.use("/public", express.static("D:/projects/"));
```

Comment: this link might can help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217771/change-directory-in-node-js-command-prompt

Comment: Have you tried `express.static("D:\\projects")`?

Comment: Yes but it shows `Cannot GET /public/`

Comment: You wont't get an index when surfing to /public/. You should browse to a file directly (http://localhost:9000/public/file1.png, if file1.png is located under D:/projects/)

Comment: Wow thanks it worked! that was simple sorry for the noob question.